# Google maps JSP in Spring

Tags: java, spring, jsp, google-maps

I have a quite big and mysterious problem. I would like to dynamically add markers to google map placed on my JSP page with coordinates from my database.

So my code looks like this one :

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
                var map;
                var markers = [];

                function initialize() {
                    var options = {
                        mapTypeControlOptions: {
                            mapTypeIds: [google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN],
                            style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU
                        }
                    }

                <%
                    String id_wydarzenia_session = null;
                    List<Koordynaty> koordynaty = null;
                    Double szer = null;
                    Double wys = null;
                    try {
                        id_wydarzenia_session = session.getAttribute("id_wydarzenia").toString();
                        WydarzenieDaoImpl wydarzeniedao = new WydarzenieDaoImpl();
                        koordynaty = wydarzeniedao.pobierzKoordynatyWydarzenia(id_wydarzenia_session);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                    }


                %>
                    var wysokoscCenter = "<%=koordynaty.get(0).getSzerokosc()%>";
                    var szerokoscCenter = "<%=koordynaty.get(0).getWysokosc()%>";
                    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'));
                    map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(wysokoscCenter, szerokoscCenter));
                    map.setZoom(17);
                    map.setMapTypeId(google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP);

                <%
                    Iterator<Koordynaty> iteratorKoordynaty = koordynaty.iterator();
                    while (iteratorKoordynaty.hasNext()) {
                        Koordynaty koordynatyDetails = iteratorKoordynaty.next();
                %>
                    addMarker(new google.maps.LatLng(koordynatyDetails.getWysokosc(), koordynatyDetails.getSzerokosc()), "Marker");
                <%
                    }
                %>

                }
                function addMarker(latlng, myTitle) {
                    markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: latlng,
                        map: map,
                        title: myTitle,
                        icon: "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/marker" + String.fromCharCode(markers.length + 65) + ".png"
                    }));
                }
            </script>
```

I checked in `addMarker` function that every coordinates are passed good, but map does not show up. I really really do not know how to fix this ;/

Comment: Are you getting any errors in console?

Comment: No. No errors at all. Only map is not showing up.

Comment: Can you 'scrape' the server generated code, make a JS fiddle out of it (and / or post that code here as well )? Can you make the static version of it behave as expected?

Comment: Yes i can, but i will do this today later (in the evening)

Comment: Where do you get the value for the markerWysokosc ? What is the format of the markerWysokosc ? Is that comma separated ?

Comment: I changed this. Sorry about this ;) Format of koordynatyDetails.getWysokosc() is of course Double for instanec 52.54545445454. I will add today a JS fiddler to make this issue more clear ;)

Comment: I add JS fiddler but something is wrong because it doesn't work : http://jsfiddle.net/GarciaPL/3NhNB/4/ . I must assure you that it works for me, but after adding database support it does not ;/

Comment: I've noticed something in you fiddle, the line: addMarker(new google.maps.LatLng(52.2319262 32898, 21.019806861877), "Alien");

Comment: @GarciaPL answer is updated with the link to working code in jsfiddle

Comment: Is it possible to call a javascript function from scriplet ? Can you put some alert or console log inside the addMarker javascript function, to make sure its called and you get the lat and lng in side

Comment: Done : http://jsfiddle.net/GarciaPL/3NhNB/13/

Comment: @GarciaPL I requested you to do some debugging in your original code   which receives the data from database, just to make sure that javascript function can be called from java code in jsp. Put some alert or console log inside the addMarker javascript function

Comment: So...it is hard to say, but i figured out that my database latitude was replace with longitude...so embarrassing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've noticed something in you fiddle, the line:

```
 addMarker(new google.maps.LatLng(52.2319262 32898, 21.019806861877), "Alien");
```

has an extra space in the first param. When I change `52.2319262 32898` to `52.231926232898` fiddle works fine. So look at what data your're getting to populate those vars.

Comment: Ok I changed this. At this moment i really don't know how to link some database in jsfiddle to show you that it doesn't work ;/

Comment: You have to 'divide and conquer', I'd eliminate data as possible problem first. Make your jsp file work fine with static data first, like the fiddle. Then work out the db stuff.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the path to the image is wrong, try this

change

```
icon: "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/marker" + String.fromCharCode(markers.length + 65) + ".png"
```

To

`http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/marker.png`

If the above change add the icons to the map then you can confirm that there is something wrong in your `String.fromCharCode(markers.length + 65)`. Your logic to add icons with A,B,C etc seems to be fine. I suspect the final URL after the `marker+String.fromCharCode(markers.length + 65)`

If the hardcoded marker paths works then try replacing the double quotes with sngle quotes (just starting and ending like in the below code)

```
icon: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/marker" + String.fromCharCode(markers.length + 65) + ".png'
```

UPDATE:

Some modifications are done to make the map and markers work see the  [working demo of your code](http://jsfiddle.net/3NhNB/9/)

You can see the map is displayed and markers added. Please go through to the code for fixes